# how to traverse / walk an arbitrary embedded structure

Tags: clojure

I want a mechanism to traverse an arbitrarily nested data structure. Then apply a fn on every node, and then check if the fn returned true at each point.

Its easy to do this with a flat structure -

```
(walk (complement string?) #(every? true? %) [ 1 2 3 4])
```

However walk doesnt work with a nested one -

```
(walk (complement string?) #(every? true? %) [ 1 2 3 [ "a" ]])
```

Using only flatten also wont work, as I will have a map as one of the forms, and I want fn applied to each value in the map too. This is the structure I will have -

```
[ ["2012" [{:a 2} {:b 3}]] ["2013" [{:a 2} {:b 3}]] ]
```

I can easily write a fn to only traverse the above and apply the fn to each val. However is there a way to write a generic mechanism for traversing?

Comment: Check out `prewalk` or `postwalk`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tree-seq might be what you want

```
(every? (complement string?)
        (remove coll?
                (tree-seq coll? #(if (map? %)
                                   (vals %)
                                   %)
                          [["2012" [{:a 2} {:b 3}]] ["2013" [{:a 2} {:b 3}]]])))
;; false

(every? (complement string?)
        (remove coll?
                (tree-seq coll? #(if (map? %)
                                   (vals %)
                                   %)
                          [[2012 [{:a 2} {:b 3}]] [2013 [{:a 2} {:b 3}]]])))
;; true
```